# My spring boot project can't access RDS DB instance used on EC2 instance

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, amazon-ec2, ssh, amazon-rds

I can access to RDS DB instance, which uses EC2 instance, by using SSH private key on MySQL Workbench. But on Intellij, I couldn't access to database to run spring boot application. How can I run this project on my local with RDS DB on Intellij?
The application-local.properties looks following.

```
...

cloud:
  aws:
    credentials:
      accessKey: xxx
      secretKey: xxx
    s3:
      bucket: my-develop
    region:
      static: ap-northeast-2


spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 50MB
      max-request-size: 50MB
  security:
    enabled: false
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
            client-secret: xxxxx
          facebook:
            client-id: xxxxxx
            client-secret: xxxx
  mvc:
    view:
      prefix: /WEB-INF/view/
      suffix: .jsp

  devtool:
    livereload:
      enabled: true
  jackson:
    serialization:
      fail-on-empty-beans: false

    default-property-inclusion: always

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://my-database.xxxx.ap-northeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/my_database?characterEncoding=utf-8&serverTimezone=UTC
    username: user
    password: password
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    platform: mysql
    initialization-mode: always
    hikari:
      connection-timeout: 5000
      validation-timeout: 1000
      minimum-idle: 20
      maximum-pool-size: 20
      max-lifetime: 30000
      leak-detection-threshold: 10000
      idle-timeout: 10000
```

Answer (score 1):

"I can access to RDS DB instance, which uses EC2 instance, by using SSH private key on MySQL Workbench." It sounds like you are using an EC2 instance as a bastion host or "jump box" to access a private RDS database. You would need to use [SSH port forwarding](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/tunneling/example) to accomplish the same thing for your local Spring Boot application.

Comment: MySQL workbench should use SSH pem file to access RDS. But in Intellij, where can I use SSH key file to access DB programmatically in Intellij?

Comment: IntelliJ won't do the SSH part for you at all. Look at that link I posted please. You will have to setup the port forwarding, in the command line, to forward the port from your local computer, through SSH on the EC2 instance, to the RDS server. After that, you can run the code in IntelliJ, using `locahost:port` as the server to connect to.